# Pygments in IronPython

Tags: ironpython, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to create ASP.NET syntax highlighter for my blog with IronPython.Hosting and Pygments. The issue is, that Pygments doesn't work on IPy 2.0 atleast without hacking.

Do you have idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this article [Pygments for Windows Live Writer](https://web.archive.org/web/20100109040325/http://devhawk.net/2009/04/05/Pygments+For+Windows+Live+Writer.aspx).

Over there is the link to the sources and misc files to compile Pygments for IronPython.